# Installing OpenCV 3.2.0 with contrib modules in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: opencv

The following command runs but ends with "incomplete configuring" instead of "completed configuring".

`cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules` ..

A few experts have given answers (not working in this case)i.e,
1. set the path for `DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH.`
2. Set "`INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES`" value to "OFF" instead of "ON" in cmake command.
3. Clean the build directory and create it again and run cmake command.
These three are also not working in this case.

I am getting the following stuff when I run cmake command.

```
-- Found VTK ver. 5.8.0 (usefile: /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/UseVTK.cmake)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:706 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "include" which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:709 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "modules" which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:712 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "doc" which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:724 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "samples" which is not an existing directory.


-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV .. =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-11-17T05:51:01Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-100-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 -
--     Disabled:                    -
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 -
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 4.x:                      YES (ver 4.8.6 EDITION = OpenSource)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so)
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 5.8.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 54.35.1)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.2 interface 7000)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.0)
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I owe you a lot if anyone can post the answer for this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.samontab.com/web/2017/06/installing-opencv-3-2-0-with-contrib-modules-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/). Works for 14.04.

Comment: I have gone through that link actually

Comment: It looks like cmake has problem finding the folders like include!! doc, module.... things that could be wrong, in my opinion: your folders are not readable (permission problem), your folders are not in the correct place (re download the repository) or maybe it is just the contrib module, which have one of the problems i stated before, or is not in that folder you are passing it. Never delete anything from the repositories you cloned...

Comment: why don't you have a look at `CMakeError.log` or post it here? My guess is that you turn `WITH_QT` on, and that requires configuration of several QT folders (concurrent, gui, test,...).

Answer (score 0):

```
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/venkatesh/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules
```

has space between `-D` and `OPENCV_`
and please check instead with:

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/venkatesh/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules /home/venkatesh/opencv/
```

and the last thing is this will only work if

1. /home/venkatesh is the directory having opencv and opencv_contrib-3.2.0 files
2. You are in a directory in /home/venkatesh/opencv/<directory_name>

commonly the directory names people give is build or release.

I wanted to comment but am somehow unable to recover my account. So I do not have enough reputations to comment.